# How can I put a callable object into the map in C++?

Tags: c++, function, lambda

I am confused why it cannot be used in this way. Is there a way to achieve a function call similar to this?I am confused why it cannot be used in this way. Is there a way to achieve a function call similar to this?

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<std::string()>> FUNCS;

void test_map_operator()
{
    FUNCS["MD5"] = [](std::string data) { return std::string("MD5 : ") + data; };
    FUNCS["CRC32"] = [](std::string data) { return std::string("CRC32 : ") + data; };
    FUNCS["RSA"] = [](std::string data, std::string key) { return std::string("RSA : ") + data + key; };

    std::cout << FUNCS["MD5"]("hello") << std::endl;
    std::cout << FUNCS["CRC32"]("hello") << std::endl;
    std::cout << FUNCS["RSA"]("hello","world") << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because the RSA has a different signature than the other two functions?

Comment: I also see that in the type declaration there's just one type. Maybe the compiler understands that that function takes no parameter but returns a string. Maybe it's a function that just takes a string but doesn't return anything. There you have functions that take 2 or 1 string parameters and return another string. Everything is quite messed up; I wouldn't compile either

Comment: I would consider specifying the argument type as well 
 std::function<std::string(std::string)>

Answer (score 4):

You can put callable objects in a map or other containers just like you do with any other data: they must be of the same type.

It seems that the type your lambdas can be converted to are `std::function<std::string(std::string)>` for MD5 and CRC32, and it is `std::function<std::string(std::string, std::string)>` for RSA. Neither matches the type you defined in the map, which is `std::function<std::string()>`.

The difference between RSA and others is a real problem in your design. For instance, how are you supposed to write a function like the following:

```
std::string format_data(std::string algo, std::string data)
{
    return FUNCS[algo](data, ¿¿¿ maybe also "some key" ???);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your function in the map is defined as:

```
std::function<std::string()
```

which means, takes no paramters and returns a std::string...
you can as workaround defined to take 2 strings as parameters and ignore the 2nd one in the lambda code for MD5 and CRC32

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<std::string(std::string, std::string)>> FUNCS;
```

--

```
FUNCS["MD5"] = [](std::string data, std::string) { return std::string("MD5 : ") + data; };
FUNCS["CRC32"] = [](std::string data, std::string) { return std::string("CRC32 : ") + data; };
FUNCS["RSA"] = [](std::string data, std::string key) { return std::string("RSA : ") + data + key; };

std::cout << FUNCS["MD5"]("hello", "") << std::endl;
std::cout << FUNCS["CRC32"]("hello", "") << std::endl;
std::cout << FUNCS["RSA"]("hello", "world") << std::endl;
```